# reaction time beween congruent and incongruent tasks using audio and vsiual modality

Tags: cognitive-psychology, reaction-time, cognitive

I am writing an experimental report in cognitive psychology, where I am finding the reaction time between congruent and incongruent tasks when I am using two different modalities- auditory and visual. *(similar to flanker task)*

A cohort of participants would first be made to the visual tasks where reaction time between congruent and incongruent is measured and after it is completed, the same participants would be made to do auditory tasks and reaction times again would be measured.
I just wanted to confirm a couple of things, which would be listed in the hypothesis and discussion, helpful if someone could provide some insights about the assumption and state if it is true or false.

1)the first hypothesis: in the visual modality, the reaction time for the congruent task would be lesser than incongruent.
2) the second hypothesis: in the auditory modality, reaction time for congruent task again would be lesser than incongruent.

I wanted to ask if anyone could provide some literature review/past studies which state whether the increase in reaction time for incongruent tasks would be greater for visual or auditory tasks as I would like to compare the results in the end between visual and auditory modality as well.

Comment: Welcome to psych.SE.  It may be helpful to be specific about the paradigm - eg, do you mean actual flanker task, or similar to flanker task (eg, Simon, stroop, priming), as I would expect different literature to address each.  There are not many unimodal auditory flanker task papers (more crossmodal), and not aware of any direct comparisons (not even sure if such comparisons would be valid...).

Comment: it is similar to flanker task